Coalescing cols where col's names vary
I have a df looking somewhat like the following:
Var1_E1_C1 <- c(1, NA, NA, 1, 1)
Var1_E1_C2 <- c(NA, 3, 2, NA, NA)
Var23_E2_C1 <- c(NA, 2, NA, 1, 1)
Var23_E2_C2 <- c(3, NA, 1, NA, NA)

data.frame(Var1_E1_C1, Var1_E1_C2, Var23_E2_C1, Var23_E2_C2)

Now I want to coalesce Var1_E1* cols to create one single Var1_E1 col and the same for Var23. Preferably with the least amount of coding as possible since my df actually has 40 pairs like this.
I am hoping to get something like this.
Var1_E1 <- c(1, 3, 2, 1, 1)
Var23_E2<- c(3, 2, 1, 1, 1)

data.frame(Var_E1, Var23_E2) 


Hi, if your issue has been resolved, you could consider accepting one of the answers you prefer by clicking the check mark. Thanks!

Not a beautiful solution, but it would generalize
Var1_E1_C1 <- c(1, NA, NA, 1, 1)
Var1_E1_C2 <- c(NA, 3, 2, NA, NA)
Var23_E2_C1 <- c(NA,2 , NA, 1, 1)
Var23_E2_C2 <- c(3,NA , 1, NA, NA)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Var1_E1_C1, Var1_E1_C2, Var23_E2_C1, Var23_E2_C2)

df %>% 
  mutate(id =  row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
  mutate(name = sub(paste0("_C",".*"),"",name)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = value)


Consider reshaping data into long format with aggregation for the coalescing, then format back to wide. Ideally, you keep data frame in long format, arguably the preferred format for most data analytics operations (merging, graphing, aggregating, plotting, etc.).
Below uses base R methods but note special changes since R 4.2. See Online Demo.
var_wide_df <- data.frame(
    Var1_E1_C1 = c(1, NA, NA, 1, 1),
    Var1_E1_C2 = c(NA, 3, 2, NA, NA),
    Var23_E2_C1 = c(NA,2 , NA, 1, 1),
    Var23_E2_C2 = c(3,NA , 1, NA, NA)
)

Long Format
var_long_df <- reshape(
    var_wide_df,
    varying = colnames(var_wide_df),
    times = colnames(var_wide_df),
    v.names = "value",
    timevar = "variable",
    direction = "long",
    new.row.names = 1:1E7
) |> within({
    x <- strsplit(variable, "_")
    Var <- sapply(x, `[`, 1)
    E <- sapply(x, `[`, 2)
    C <- sapply(x, `[`, 3)
    VarE <- paste(Var, E, sep="_")
    rm(x)
}) |> aggregate(
    x = value ~ id + VarE, # 'x' arg replaced 'formula' since R 4.2
    data = _,              # Pipe placeholder added since R 4.2
    FUN = max, na.rm = TRUE,
    na.action = na.omit
) 
var_long_df
#    id     VarE value
# 1   1  Var1_E1     1
# 2   2  Var1_E1     3
# 3   3  Var1_E1     2
# 4   4  Var1_E1     1
# 5   5  Var1_E1     1
# 6   1 Var23_E2     3
# 7   2 Var23_E2     2
# 8   3 Var23_E2     1
# 9   4 Var23_E2     1
# 10  5 Var23_E2     1

Wide Format
new_var_wide_df <- reshape(
    idvar = "id",
    v.names = "value",
    timevar = "VarE",
    direction = "wide",
    sep = "_"
)

new_var_wide_df
#   id value_Var1_E1 value_Var23_E2
# 1  1             1              3
# 2  2             3              2
# 3  3             2              1
# 4  4             1              1
# 5  5             1              1


You can use tapply + dplyr::coalesce:
tapply(c(df), sub("(.+)_(.+)", "\\1", names(df)),
       \(x) do.call(dplyr::coalesce, x)) |>
  as.data.frame.list()

#   Var1_E1 Var23_E2
# 1       1        3
# 2       3        2
# 3       2        1
# 4       1        1
# 5       1        1


Another solution is to stack C1 and C2 separately, find the first non-missing element from them, and transform to wider format.
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowid_to_column("id") %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c("name", ".value"), names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)") %>%
  mutate(value = coalesce(C1, C2)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id)

# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#      id Var1_E1 Var23_E2
#   <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1       1        3
# 2     2       3        2
# 3     3       2        1
# 4     4       1        1
# 5     5       1        1

